# In Spectre how does the DNA match work?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, spectre

So I have seen Spectre twice now and I'm confused about one thing.

When 007 gives Q the ring he puts it on his magical scanner thingie and his laptop eventually pops up with "DNA Match" (or something along those lines). The program he is running then promptly puts it into a nice graphic with the faces of all the villains with lines connected the baddies to each other (Also inside an octopus shape... lol).

My question is how is the DNA found on the ring meant to match the 8-ish bad guys? My current running theory is that maybe the ink in the ring matched some rare octopus or something. Did I miss an explanation for this in the movie?

Comment: @Richard Ha I find it mildly amusing you edited thingo to thingie :P.

Comment: In fairness, both are real words; [thingo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thingo) vs. [thingie](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263791/thingy-or-thingie)

Comment: I have no issue with it it just made me giggle out loud for some reason.

Comment: I watched once, I thought that they all had worn that same ring at some point... Which also didn't make sense to me.

Comment: Theories, schmeories. Why not just [ask the Director](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43997/7812)? :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue was dealt with in a [podcast interview](https://soundcloud.com/empiremagazine/spectre-spoiler-special-sam-mendes) between Empire Magazine and the film's Director, Sam Mendez:

To quote from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/JamesBond/comments/3sjlye/empire_magazine_spectre_spoiler_special_podcast/cwxre0p)

> *One of the biggest plot holes, the SPECTRE ring identifying previously
>   encountered SPECTRE members is explained: **Q's analysis (if you freeze
>   frame it) is supposed to indicate the ring is made of iridium, which
>   is an extremely rare element known for having high density and
>   resistance to corrosion. Toxicology from the shown members was to
>   indicate traces of this element discovered in autopsy, which is how Q
>   links it together.** Apparently Mendes left out the exposition on this
>   scene because outside of the members, it's basically telling you
>   information you already know: That Obenhauser is the head of SPECTRE.*

Comment: Brilliant listening to the podcast now. But that makes much more sense.

Answer (score 4):

Its been a few days since I've seen it, by my impression was that it *wasn't* a DNA match, it was a fingerprint match.

When he put the ring on the magical scanner thingie it uses some magical super-high-tech cameras to take high res scans of the ring and pick out the fingerprints ([which actually sort of already exists](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2014/dec/30/hacker-fakes-german-ministers-fingerprints-using-photos-of-her-hands)). From that point, its just a matter of matching fingerprints in a database, plus some silly Hollywood style illogical UIs and you get the scene!

Comment: I almost certain it says dna match, as per what i think it says in the movie. I will have to go see it again I guess to confirm haha. Even if you are correct and it is fingerprints, I may be wrong, but to not get a partial match would there not have to be enough surface area on the ring for 8 finger prints. Also there are several scenes where, again i could be wrong, James Q and maybe mr white handle the ring by hand which could rub of the finger prints. Also why would all of these bad guys touch the one ring? This would seem odd especially because as stated in the movie they very rarely meet.

Comment: @Spaceman I think that all falls under "Hollywood magic"

Comment: your most likely correct with the Hollywood magic statement. It just ticks me off that they bother to try an explain the link. But do it in such a weird way.

Comment: I've reluctantly downvoted. Although this is an excellent theory, it is also (alas) incorrect.